# Trigger bootstrap tooltip options via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Pls what is the right way to pass options via javascript for bootstrap tooltip/popover:
Via data attributes works as in:

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-animation="fade" data-delay="200" data-trigger="focus" data-content="foo">
```

But using javascript this doesn't:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("input").popover()({
            animation:"fade",
            delay: "200",
            trigger:"focus",
            placement: "right"
        });
    });
</script>
```

what is the right syntax?

Answer (score 5):

For `tooltip`, it should be:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("input").tooltip({...});
});
```

Instead of:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("input").popover({...});
});
```

**Update:** Sorry for the mis-confusions, [it works here](http://jsfiddle.net/uw4w3/2/) but:

```
popover()({...});
```

Should be

```
popover({...});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-animation="fade" data-delay="200" data-trigger="focus" data-content="foo">
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("input").popover({
        animation:"fade",
        delay: "200",
        trigger:"focus",
        placement: "right"
    });
});
```

Make sure you have added the `JavaScript` and `CSS` files properly.

Comment: I want use a popover. Note: The `$("input").popover()` works when i pass options via data attributes as in the first example and so does`$("input").tooltip()`. Both don't work via javascript

Comment: That's because you're just initializing the popover with it's options (or like above without any options).  To call the popover and cause it to display you need to use $('input').popover('show');

Comment: little errors in value definition:

$("input").popover({
        animation:true,
        delay: 200,
        trigger:"focus",
        placement: "right"
    });

Answer (score 3):

Reveals an element's tooltip.

```
$('#element').tooltip('show')
```

Hides an element's tooltip.

```
$('#element').tooltip('hide')
```

Toggles an element's tooltip.

```
$('#element').tooltip('toggle')
```

Hides and destroys an element's tooltip.

```
$('#element').tooltip('destroy')
```

Complete reference: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)